# Ping function having undesirable results

Tags: php

I previously asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030789/pinging-an-ip-address-using-php-and-echoing-the-result) on how to create a ping function and came up with the follow:

```
<?php
function pingAddress($ip) {
    $pingresult = exec("ping -n 3 $ip", $outcome, $status);
    if (1 != $status) {
        $status = "alive";
    } else {
        $status = "dead";
    }
    echo "The IP address, $ip, is  ".$status;
}
```

This had the desired results until I noticed that it was returning IP address 192.168.0.3 as alive when I knew it wasn't.

I checked through my standard windows command prompt and it was returning the following:

```
Reply from 192.168.0.2: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.0.2: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.0.2: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.0.2: Destination host unreachable.
```

I'm assuming that the function think its alive due to the way its written and how it returns 'Reply from'? However I'm not too sure - can anyone shed some light on it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its exit value for that type of error is not `1`, therefore your condition would have undesired results.  Try the following:

```
if ($status == 0) {
    $status = "alive";
} else {
    $status = "dead";
}
```

Comment: I've changed the exit value accordingly but still getting identical results (192.168.0.3 returning alive although destination unreachable)

Comment: @Bernard:  Under which system are you running `ping`?

Comment: @Bernard:  The version of `ping` included in Windows is exiting with a status of `0` for me as well, with those arguments.  Doing a `strpos` for the string `Destination host unreachable.` would be an alternative to checking the exit status.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ man ping

...

RETURN VALUES
     The ping utility returns an exit status of zero if at least one response
     was heard from the specified host; a status of two if the transmission
     was successful but no responses were received; or another value (from
     <sysexits.h>) if an error occurred.
```

You should be checking for a return code of `0`, not `!= 1`.