# how to ping ip addresses in php and give results

Tags: php, ip-address, ping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pinging an IP address using PHP and echoing the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030789/pinging-an-ip-address-using-php-and-echoing-the-result)

How do you ping an ip addresses in php. and give the the results as if you are on cmd program in windows

```
<?php

  system(‘ping -c 192.168.0.104’); // Ping IP address.<br>

   echo “pinged”;<br>

?>
```

Comment: You get answer from this please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030789/pinging-an-ip-address-using-php-and-echoing-the-result

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$ip =   "127.0.0.1";
exec("ping -n 3 $ip", $output, $status);
print_r($output);
```

output looks like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
    [2] => Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
    [3] => Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
    [4] => Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
    [5] => 
    [6] => Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    [7] =>     Packets: Sent = 3, Received = 3, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
    [8] => Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    [9] =>     Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
)
```

Comment: I got the empty array like this,  
Array ( ) 

can you help me?

Comment: If you got empty array `Array()` try to use `-c 3` instead of `-n 3`. You might be running linux server instead of windows. Linux ping doesn't recognize `-n` option.

Comment: does 3 means the command will be executed thrice?

Comment: Be sure to use `escapeshellcmd` to ensure that users cannot execute arbitrary commands

Comment: I created a good tool based on this working script with few changes: https://pingiponline.com/

Answer (score 26):

Try this

```
$host="192.168.0.104";

exec("ping -c 4 " . $host, $output, $result);

print_r($output);

if ($result == 0)

echo "Ping successful!";

else

echo "Ping unsuccessful!";
```

Note: This is dependant on the OS you are running. Windows will default to only 4 pings while Linux will ping forever.

To ping twice in Windows, use "ping -n 2 host"

To ping twice in Linux, use "ping -c 2 host"

Answer (score 2):

I just pinged google with that [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

```
<?php
echo exec("ping www.google.com");
?>
```

output was:

```
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```