# What's wrong here? (newbie)

Tags: php

I need to check if there is an internet-connection before actually sending the email. Everything works fine until I add this code and function:

```
if(doesConnectionExist())
{
    $errors .= "\n No internet connection!";
}
```

plus this function:

```
function doesConnectionExist
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var file = "http://www.?????.com/somefile.png";
    var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
    xhr.open('HEAD', file + "?rand=" + randomNum, false);
    try {
        xhr.send();
        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 304) {
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The total code looks like this:

```
<?php 
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=iso8859-15');
$your_email ='????@????.com';
session_start();
$errors = '';
$firstname = ' ';
$lastname = '';
$visitor_email = '';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];

if(empty($firstname)||empty($lastname)
{
    $errors .= "\n firstname and lastname are required fields. ";   
}


if(doesConnectionExist())
{
    $errors .= "\n No internet connection!";
}


if(empty($errors))
{
    $to = $your_email;
    $subject="test";
    $from = $your_email;
    $body = "test\n".
    "Firstname: $firstname\n".
    "Lastname: $lastname \n".
    $headers = "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
    header('Location: thankyou.html');
}
}

function doesConnectionExist
    {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var file = "http://www.?????.com/somefile.png";
    var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
    xhr.open('HEAD', file + "?rand=" + randomNum, false);
    try {
        xhr.send();
        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 304) {
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

If anybody could help me would be absolutely great!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: you missed () in the function "doesConnectionExist".

Comment: You appear to be mixing JavaScript and PHP.  They are two completely different languages.

Comment: Oeps!
That of course is a main issue....
Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Your `doesConnectionExist` is javascript, not PHP =)

You can use this post to ping the server and check internet connection :

[StackOverflow : Ping IP addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283674/how-to-ping-ip-addresses-in-php-and-give-results)

EDIT :

```
<?php 
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=iso8859-15');
$your_email ='????@????.com';
session_start();
$errors = '';
$firstname = ' ';
$lastname = '';
$visitor_email = '';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];

if(empty($firstname)||empty($lastname)
{
    $errors .= "\n firstname and lastname are required fields. ";   
}


if(doesConnectionExist('http://www.?????.com/somefile.png'))
{
    $errors .= "\n No internet connection!";
}


if(empty($errors))
{
    $to = $your_email;
    $subject="test";
    $from = $your_email;
    $body = "test\n".
    "Firstname: $firstname\n".
    "Lastname: $lastname \n".
    $headers = "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
    header('Location: thankyou.html');
}
}

function doesConnectionExist($host)
{
    exec("ping -c 4 " . $host, $output, $result);

    if ($result == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you ThinkTank for your answer.
How do I implement this in my code?
Is it possible you put it in?
Thanks