# How to ping ip address - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I hope this is not a duplicate but I could not find a laravel IP address ping..., I have this:
`Ping::check('http://example.com');` which returns 200 if website is alive or 0 if not, but it doesnt work on DNS or IPs...

For example, the DNS is: `server.sols-rpg.com:7777` and it also has a port as you can see `7777`, it is a SAMP server, if I go to a DNS lookup, some will also tell me that it is online and running, or some will just give me its IP, but still, how can I ping it?

Comment: There are no ports with `ping`. It's ICMP, which has [no such thing](https://serverfault.com/questions/309357/ping-a-specific-port). You could try [`fsockopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) to see if a port is open.

Comment: check this see if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283674/how-to-ping-ip-addresses-in-php-and-give-results

Comment: @HanlinWang But how can I do this with laravel, there is no `exec("ping -n 3 $ip", $output, $status);` for laravel

Comment: that's a php function, it exists in every php application, laravel is a php application too, so you can use it directly

Comment: @Krok Laravel is a PHP framework. You can use literally any PHP code in it. There doesn't have to be a built-in Laravel command to do so.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add a `;` and it told me that it was unexpected.

Comment: Please avoid use of exec. All together. There is alternatives