# PHP file_get_contents check source online or not before do the execution

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm using PHP `file_get_contents` to read text file data.

Assuming I have 2 IP Address, 1 online and 1 offline:

```
192.168.180.181 - Online
192.168.180.182 - Offline
```

And the PHP

```
$fileAccept = file_get_contents("\\\\192.168.180.181\\Reports\\".$dModel['MODEL_NAME'].$source."\\Accept\\Accept_".$dDtl['MODEL_CODE']."_".$dateCode."_".$dDtl['TS_CODE'].".txt");
```

As We Know IP Address `192.168.180.182` is offline, then I tried to run the code. And result the page always loading.

My question, how can I prevent it maybe first need to check the IP is alive or not, if alive then can continue to next step.

Maybe something like this:

```
if(IP IS OFFLINE)
{
    echo "do not do anything";
}
else
{
    echo "do something";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like that

```
$scc = stream_context_create(array('http'=>
    array(
        'timeout' => 120,  //120 seconds 
    )
));
$url = "http://192.168.180.181/....";
$handle =  file_get_contents('$url, false, $scc);
```

you can create two handles and check whether is ok with if statement, of course you can change the timeout to suites you

Update:
if accessing file locally you can check this stream_set_timeout() function , the [documentation is here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php)

Comment: He's not using HTTP to access the file. It's being accessed using the normal filesystem, but it's on an SMB server.

Comment: same approach using stream_set_timeout() which uses fopen() handler as first parameter, i will add the doc link in my answer

Comment: But you need to change `'http'=>` to something else.

Comment: you will access the file locally using fopen() , and as far as i know http is available localy too

Comment: `stream_set_timeout()` requires a stream argument. But you need to call `fopen()` to get a stream, and that will hang if the fileserver is down.

Comment: @MohammedOmer Is it can use if the url like this `\\192.168.180.182` ?

Comment: @HiDayurieDave i believe yes fopen can handle path like this

Comment: Tried and it's not working, the execution still long time if that IP Address is offline

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on pinging the IP you need to check

```
class IPChecker{

    public static function isIPOnline($ip){

        switch (SELF::currentOS()){
            case "windows":
                $arg = "n";
                break;
            case "linux":
                $arg = "c";
                break;
            default: throw new \Exception('unknown OS');
        }

        $result = "";
        $output = [];
        // to debug errors add 2>&1 to the command to fill $output
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665041/php-why-isnt-exec-returning-output
        exec("ping -$arg 2 $ip " , $output, $result);
        // if 0 then the there is no errors like "Destination Host Unreachable"
        if ($result === 0) return true;
        return false;
    }


    public static function currentOS(){
        if(strpos(strtolower(PHP_OS), "win") !== false) return 'windows';
        elseif (strpos(strtolower(PHP_OS), "linux") !== false) return 'linux';
        //TODO: extend other OSs here
        else return 'unknown';

    }

}
```

usage example

```
var_dump( IPChecker::isIPOnline("192.168.180.181") );// should outputs bool(true) 
var_dump( IPChecker::isIPOnline("192.168.180.182") );// should outputs bool(false)
```

I have used these answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482260/how-to-get-the-os-on-which-php-is-running/12997081), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283674/how-to-ping-ip-addresses-in-php-and-give-results/13283707)) in my answer