# Pinging a server in php without the port?

Tags: php, ping

I have been having problems with a script i have been tampering with.

I am trying to make an online checker for my game server, so i can indicate if my server is online or down from my website. Here is my code:

```
<?php
if (!$socket = @fsockopen(IP, Port, $errno, $errstr, 2))
{
  echo "<center><img style='float:left;' src='images/offline_icon.png'><font style='float:left;' size='5' color='red'><strong>Offline!</strong></font></center>";
}
else 
{
  echo "<center><img style='float:left;' src='images/online_icon.png'><font style='float:left;' size='5' color='green'><strong>Online!</strong></font></center>";
  fclose($socket);
}
?>
```

My problem is, it fails. If i set the timeout to 30, it would wait thirty seconds, then mark it as offline and continue.

If i however ping the IP in terminal, it works just fine.

After searching about about ping and ports, it seems it might be the problem.

Is there a way to execute a normal ping on an IP without the port? Like linux command line?

Comment: Is the game server also running a web server? If so, could you use a small html file to determine if it was alive instead? `file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/alive.html');` it returns false on failure.

Comment: The game server is hosted remotely. I already knew that was possible :(

Comment: Try to use port 80, that's the port `http://` uses.

Comment: I know, but the server is not hosting any web server.

Comment: I don't know if this works, but try this function (using `socket_create`): http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php#101012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ICMP doesn't use a port.

You might want to use `exec()` to ping the server. Check out: [Pinging an IP address using PHP and echoing the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030789/pinging-an-ip-address-using-php-and-echoing-the-result)