# Check game server ping in a browser?

Tags: web-services, server, ping

I've been researching around regarding the capabilities of having a client access a website and check their ping in a game (so far there seems to be no possible way using JS, however there may be a way with AJAX?). Without a website, the method to check ping would be using the command-line ping command to the server address through ICMP. Would it be possible to check the ping of a client to the game server with a website middle-man?

EDIT: If I do a php solution as described here: [Pinging a server in php without the port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232221/pinging-a-server-in-php-without-the-port?rq=1)
could I do something like checking the ping of client to my website, then checking from my website to the game server and then predict the ping of the client?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really use ping command from js, but you can use AJAX call to some empty file on your server, to measure the response time:

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
$.ajax('http://your_server/empty_file')
.always(function( data ) {
    console.log(new Date().getTime()-start);
});
```

EDIT: you can only 'ping' game server using this method if it has HTTP server running on it (you may need to set up headers to enable cross-domain requests for that). If both servers are on the same fast local network, there is no need to ping to both servers separately, the measurments are going to be the same.

Comment: Is there a way to measure response time of a server I do not own? This server being accessible over ICMP

Comment: Actually, you can still use code snippet above to ping servers you don't own, and even if they don't have HTTP service on them: the ajax will still try to connect, which means packets will be sent, and some kind of response will be received. You still just need to measure the time and ignore the errors. The only case this will not work is if port 80 of those servers is blocked by firewall.