# Show Average Ping Latency using PHP

Tags: php

How to show average ping latency using PHP ?

The example is here : http://www.gameserverstatus.com/aura_kingdom_server_status

Thank you.

Comment: Please explain further what is your intent. Do you want to ping *from* your server to another one? What is your OS? What was your attempt so far to achieve it?

Comment: I will suggest you to see this first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030789/pinging-an-ip-address-using-php-and-echoing-the-result
Then getting the average will be ( sum_all_pings / count_all_pings)

Comment: Yeah i want to ping from my computer to another one. I am using Windows 7