# Is any PHP Script available which is able to Ping an IP Address

Tags: php

I want to ask is any php script available which is able to ping an IP Address if is it so let me know how we can do that ...?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030789/pinging-an-ip-address-using-php-and-echoing-the-result

Comment: Every 30 seconds? Even when there's no incoming request? Are you sure you want to do this in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ip =   "127.0.0.1";
exec("ping -n 3 $ip", $output, $status);
print_r($output);
```

Output will be an Array. Something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
    [2] => Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
    [3] => Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
    [4] => Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
    [5] => 
    [6] => Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    [7] =>     Packets: Sent = 3, Received = 3, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
    [8] => Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    [9] =>     Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
)
```

Answer (score 0):

On linux, you the use the following :

```
<?php
    function ping($ip) {
        $result = exec("/bin/ping -n 3 $ip", $outcome, $status);
        if (0 == $status) {
            $status = "alive";
        } else {
            $status = "dead";
        }
        echo $status;
    }

    ping("80.80.80.80");

?>
```