# Generate IP address and Subnet + Ping

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am new but not so new to PHP and SQL but still a very long way to go to understand everything.

I have searched whole morning on the internet for a solution since I have done it before but geez I should have saved my code..

Here is my question:

Let's say I have an internal IP range 192.168.1.0/24

I want to populate the whole range of the 254 IP addresses which would be in table format. There should only go 1-2 pings to IP with an icon that shows if an IP is up or not.

Please see the below image for what I want but with PHP Coding. And just more IP address

[image: Example]

Thanx in advance.

Comment: "but geez i should have saved my code.."
Yes, You should. Where is Your problem?

Comment: Start a step by step research: 1. How can I generate IP list? (arrays basically) 2.How to store them(MYSQL) 3. How to [ping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030789/pinging-an-ip-address-using-php-and-echoing-the-result)? 4. How to ping every hour let's say(Cron jobs)

Comment: Thanx i would look into these.. Needed that start point again since i was not coding for a few months.

Comment: Are you using linux?

Comment: I have this which I picked from a few answers on SO, it should give you a head start for getting IP addresses anyway. https://eval.in/994003