# Check for system updates with PHP on Debian-based

Tags: php, apt-get, debian-based

I am developing a PHP monitoring platform and I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030789/pinging-an-ip-address-using-php-and-echoing-the-result). It works very well and I would like to do the same for an `apt-get update`. Is it possible to check if there are system updates available with PHP? I have no idea how to deal with the output of `apt-get update`.

Comment: Try and after ask a better question, with your solution provided.

Comment: You can capture the output of apt the same way the answers in the post you mentioned do. The problem would be that you have to parse the output, because I think apt doesn't return non-0 if no updates are available, because the check on a system level stays successful. For the parsing you could use sed or perl/php itself.

Comment: as far as I know, this is not possible in PHP. This has to be done through commands in your console. How ever you could write a cronjob for this. Information: https://askubuntu.com/questions/923535/schedule-apt-get-script-using-cron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        $o  = `apt list --upgradable`;
        $upgratable = explode("\n", $o);
        $l = count($upgratable);
        $u = [];
        for($i=1; $i<$l-1; $i++){
            $u[substr($upgratable[$i],0,strpos($upgratable[$i], ' '))] = substr($upgratable[$i],strpos($upgratable[$i], ' '));

        }
        dump($u);


// btw
//        pingAddress('https://stackoverflow.com'); // The IP address, https://stackoverflow.com, is dead
//        pingAddress('127.0.0.1'); // The IP address, 127.0.0.1, is dead
```