# PHP Shell exec from address bar

Tags: php, linux, shell, browser, ssh

I want use the PHP script for execution commands from address bar.

For example :

```
the-site.com/shell.php?exec=ls%20/
```

In browser I see this result :

```
bin
lib
etc
home
usr
```

Comment: What's your question? And please be more specific than "How do I do it?"

Comment: It is my idea, but I can't write any code... I doesn't know PHP. This script I will use on my router. Only for me.

Comment: Why not use, erm, Shell?

Comment: Think you is a good idea? the-site.com/shell.php?exec=rm%20-rf%20//

Comment: SSH is good. But sometimes I must use browser because I haven't SSH client (on my WP-Phone or TV, for example).

Comment: You do NOT want commands to be executable by a publicly-accessible PHP script, no matter *how* secure you think it may be. Hackers will *always* beat it eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but I'd advise against it - you're opening yourself up to all kinds of trouble.

Consider accidentally sending `rm -rf /`.

If you *must* do this, use a (white)list of tried and tested commands and only allow your script to execute these, then restrict access to the script's entry-point to your internal network only.

I'd post some code for you but, to be honest, I'd worry that you would just use it without testing it - or more importantly understanding it.

Essentially, you're looking at something like:-

```
$whitelist = array(/* list of allowed commands */);

if (/* command in whitelist */) {
    execute();
}
```

You'll do doubt be needing to pass parameters to your scripts at some point, so make you sure you validate and [escape](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) them too. Here's an interesting post with some pointers and links for you to read:-

[Best way to sanitize exec command with user inserted variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982904/best-way-to-sanitize-exec-command-with-user-inserted-variables)